# Why sometime query take 3 second for complete job

Tags: php, mysql

The application is real time site that need a **speed of access on every query** (select, update, insert) Low latency must less than 200ms every query

Well, On average 98% each query. time is less than 0.001-0.005 secound on for complete job query.

**the problem is
Sometime around 5 time per hour, they can take up to 1s and may be 5s, i don't know real cause of problem**

i found to reducing the problem are move that from INNODB to MEMORY.

> **THE QUESTION are Why sometime the query can take time up to 5 secound ?**

```
Example query in sometime query more than 1 secound

# Time: 130328 20:27:40
# User@Host: ferge572w[ferge572w] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 1.339712  Lock_time: 0.000026 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
SET timestamp=1364477260;
UPDATE log_product SET credit=credit+1 WHERE id_product='149721921' and id_user='2029275' LIMIT 1;

table index: id_product, id_user
No.row: 33,491   table size: 5Mb

# Time: 130329  7:25:37
# User@Host: ferge572w[ferge572w] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 1.439856  Lock_time: 0.000031 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
SET timestamp=1364516737;
UPDATE product SET lastuser='hello',picperson='1',lastid='2030505',country='thailand',price=price+0.01,time=DATE_ADD(time, INTERVAL 3 SECOND) WHERE id='349721227' LIMIT 1;

table index: id
No.row: 35   table size: 2.1Mb
```

i ensure EXPLAIN to optimize query and update use index. also checked data types and their lengths of the fields of the table but still problem

---

**UPDATE** i find the cause of problem are when system High IOwait. the slow query heppen Immediate.
How to fix it

Slow query when IO wait is high.

> **Show from iotop command**
>
> -- TID -- PRIO -- USER -- DISK READ -- DISK WRITE -- SWAPIN -- IO> -- COMMAND
>
> -- 2311 -- be/4 -- mysql -- 0.00 B/s --  0.00 B/s -- 0.00% -- 96.25% -- mysql~l.sock
>
> -- 2311 -- be/4 -- mysql -- 0.00 B/s --  0.00 B/s -- 0.00% -- 96.25% -- mysql~l.sock
>
> -- 2311 -- be/4 -- mysql -- 0.00 B/s --  0.00 B/s -- 0.00% -- 96.24% -- mysql~l.sock
>
> **High IO wait start when 6:13:28 PM - 6:13:29 PM (sar command)**
>
> --------------------- CPU -- %usr -- %nice -- %sys -- %iowait -- %steal
>
> -- 6:13:28 PM --- all -- 2.53 -- 0.00 -- 2.02 -- **39.39** -- 0.00
>
> -- 6:13:29 PM --- all -- 1.99 -- 0.00 -- 1.00 -- **49.25** -- 0.00
>
> **Got slow query between that time**
>
> Time: 130329 18:13:29
>
> User@Host: wdwdwd[wdwdwd] @ localhost []
>
> Query_time: 2.007902  Lock_time: 0.000025 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1 SET timestamp=1364555609;
>
> UPDATE log_product SET credit=credit+1 WHERE id_product='349721228' and id_user='2021841' LIMIT 1;

Comment: Perhaps use a service like munin to create these pretty graphs over time so you can see if there are time-based patterns. http://oierud.name/bliki/ImprovedMuninGraphsForMySQL.html

Comment: Do you have totutial to setup munin. CentOS 6.4. thank

Comment: if you can reappear this problem that try use profile http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-profile.html

Comment: i found the cause, updated above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be a number of reasons, the more data you have (and check) the closer you'll get to finding your answer.

## Things to check:

- Are you on shared hosting, they can be unreliable.
- Have you checked mySQL slow logs
- Have you done a mysql explain on your queries?
- Are you getting lots of requests at the time your SQL queries are too slow, disk IO could be an issue
- Do your tables need to be optimised?
- Are you running out of memory on the machine?

http://newrelic.com/ can be very helpful in these situations (and they have a free version which you can take advantage of)

## Potential Reasons:

- Disk I/O: You are on shared hosting and/or your server's disk is
  unreliable/saturated at times
- Peak Usage: Lots of traffic/queries at specific times causing delays
- Other Server related slowdowns: e.g AntiVirus or another process is running and chewing up resources

If you're able to do more analysis of your data as I and others have suggested it could prove very valuable in getting to the bottom of your particular issue

Comment: Yes, i ensure EXPLAIN to optimize query and update use index. also checked data types and their lengths of the fields of the table but still problem in sometime

Comment: What sort of hosting are you using. From the information so far I suspect your disk I/O could be an issue. Maybe cheap/shared hosting?

Comment: Yes, i found the problem in hosting.

Comment: If you think my answer (which included HOSTING as a reason) was correct feel free to mark it as the correct one. If you have further information or questions please let me know.

Comment: Thank for your answer, Do you recommend a tool for monitor Mysql or mornitor Centos with log or may be graph monitor ?

Comment: A few I've used in the past are newrelic, nagios, opsview & Server Density

Answer (score 2):

Always take care of some points specially with big database ;

1. Check the slow query logs of mysql
2. Check the indexes as on update indexes need to be managed again by the RDBMS.
3. Check the data types and their lengths of the fields of the table because in proper datatype may also cause performance issues.
4. Use EXPLAIN to optimize query
5. Choose proper storage engine as per application requirement

Comment: Yes, i ensure EXPLAIN to optimize query and update use index. also checked data types and their lengths of the fields of the table but still problem

Answer (score 0):

Such vary results might have network nature. 
For ex. on Windows host you can try to use '127.0.0.1' intead of 'localhost', because localhost by default is mapped to IP6 address and it have some issues with MySQL server.

Answer (score 0):

check numer of the images/Query through direct php  / AJAX calls, and number of JS files included in the page, then try

Comment: No, it now about client process. it about process in php backend only.